# How to add child elements of SOAP request without namespace JAVA

Tags: java, soap

I am trying to build a SOAP message and I need to get rid of the namespace in the child elements.

Tried as below

```
QName childName = new QName("","objRequest","tem");
```

and I get the exception org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.

I tried it as

```
SOAPElement bodyElement1 =bodyElement.addChildElement("objRequest","tem");
```

and still get the default namespace added as

```
<tem:objRequest xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
```

I want the element to be added as `<tem:objRequest>` instead of above.
Pls let me know if there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add the namespace to the envelope

```
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("tem","http://tempuri.org/")
```

I assume you do not apply xml/xslt transformation to get the result String.